# Select Dynamic Range (rows) and count colored cells - VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table with colored cells.  I need, through VBA User form, to count the relevant current row in the table. 
I'm not sure how to use the right syntax for dynamic range.
Here is my code:

What i'm doing wrong?

```
Public Function UpdateTestCompletion()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim CurrentRange As Range
T_R = 1 'dynamic variable - set 1 just for test -mention the row count in the table starting from D_start cell
Set sht = Worksheets("Test_Data")
Set StartCell = Sheets("Test_Data").Range("D_Start").Offset(T_R, 8)
'Find Last Column
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
'the last raw of tests parameters
'Select Range
CurrentRange = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, LastColumn))

TotalGreen = CountColor(CurrentRange)
TComp_L.Caption = (TotalGreen / Sheets("T_list").Range("N14").Value) & " %"

End Function
```

Here is the code of 'TotalGreen' function (also doesn't work):

```
Function CountColor(range_data As Range) As Long
Dim datax As Range
Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = RGB(169, 208, 142) 'green
For Each datax In range_data
   If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
     CountColor = CountColor + 1
   End If
Next datax
End Function
```

Please your help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.Interior.ColorIndex` refers to Excel's built in Color values.  Use `Range.Interior.Color` to refer to `RGB` colors.

```
Function CountColor(range_data As Range, Optional xcolor As Long = -1) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim Count As Long
    If xcolor = -1 Then xcolor = RGB(169, 208, 142)   'green
    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.Color = xcolor Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next datax
    CountColor = Count
End Function
```

Reference: [Excel VBA color code list – ColorIndex, RGB color, VB color](http://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-color-code-list/)

Comment: Thank you, the function work now, but i still have a problem with the range syntax, how to send it to the function

Comment: I check the countcolor function by sending regular range.when i send to this function the range in'CurrentRange' as appered in 'UpdateTestCompletion' function, i get the error massage: 'Object variable or with block variable not set' when it stucking on: 
    CurrentRange = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, LastColumn))

Comment: In the VBA you need to `Set` Object variables. `Set CurrentRange = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, LastColumn))`